# How does the properties of a soil affect gamma-radiation?

Tags: gamma-rays

I'm doing data-analysis on airborne gamma-ray data and I have the following statement given which I don't fully understand and I would need some help interpreting it:

> "Gamma radiation attenuation is affected by density, porosity, particle size and water content of the soil. Increase of fine aggregate in the soil causes the water content to increase, and hence the density increases as well, causing an attenuation of gamma radiation."

Is my interpretation correct:

"The more dense and wet the soil is the less gamma-radiation is reflected back from the soil"

Hope my questions is appropriate here. I'm not a physicist so could you please explain this to me in simple terms if possible? :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are almost correct. The denser the soil the harder for the gamma radiation to enter deep into the particular soil

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to have anything to do with reflection, but rather with penetration of the gamma rays *through* the soil.

In layman terms, the correct summary is: "the more dense and wet the soil is, the more it blocks gamma rays from passing through".